# How to create a file by suffixing an Uri on Android. Shared storage

Tags: android

I want to create a file on a specific Uri, retrieve from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.
For example, maybe the uri will point to `Download/A/`
and I want to create the file `Download/A/a.txt`.

I should have the necessary permission, as i requested them

```
contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
    uri,
    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
)
```

And i'm able to fetch all metadata in the directory.

I tested this but i get an error:

```
val fileUri: Uri = repoUri.toUri().buildUpon().appendPath("./a.txt").build()
                                    Log.d(TAG, fileUri.path.toString())
                                    fileUri.toFile().writeBytes("helloworld".encodeToByteArray())
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Uri lacks 'file' scheme: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload%2FA/.%2Fa.txt
```

But i'm not sure if this is the way of doing it

Comment: No that is not the way to go. You should first create a DocumentFile instance for the obtained directory uri and then use CreateFile() on that instance.